# Obey the testing goat - OperationalError

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-migrations

I am going through Obey the testing goat book and stumbled upon this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table lists_item has no column named list_id
```

It only appears when I am on a dev server (when I am running tests it works like a charm).

The book explains that it can happen [here](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/chapter_prettification.html):

> If you spin up your dev server with manage.py runserver, you may run into a database error "table lists_item has no column named list_id". You need to update your local database to reflect the changes we made in models.py. Use manage.py migrate. If it gives you any grief about IntegrityErrors, just delete[1] the database file and try again.

I am doing what it says, but error does not disappear. Maybe anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Make sure you run `manage.py makemigrations` before `manage.py migrate`. If that doesn't work, please show the migration files for the `lists` app. The output of `manage.py showmigrations lists` might help debugging as well.

Answer (score 0):

Django's `makemigrations` is responsible for creating `new migrations based on the changes detected to your models` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemigrations).

You should run `makemigrations` before running `migrate`, as the latter applies the new migrations detected by the former to the database.

Comment: I have deleted the database and run migrations (makemigrations and then migrate) again. When I run the server and try to add new item to the list it goes like this: https://imgur.com/mea7Tco

Comment: Did you delete `__pycache__` as well? Could you post the related `models.py` (or `forms.py` or `views.py`)?